# Trying to install webpack 5 with react 17 for module federation, getting this error on npm install

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a react app created with cra. I want to install webpack in order to setup module federation.

I am getting this error on running the below command:

```
$ npm i --D webpack@5.24.0 webpack-cli webpack-server html-webpack-plugin babel-loader webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: netlify-foot@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.9" from webpack-server@0.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack-server
npm ERR!   dev webpack-server@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-05T15_25_05_470Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

What is the issue? How to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Your install command is:

```sh
npm i --D webpack@5.24.0 webpack-cli webpack-server html-webpack-plugin babel-loader webpack-dev-server
```

This means, it tries to add the following six packages:

- webpack@5.24.0
- webpack-cli
- webpack-server
- html-webpack-plugin
- babel-loader
- webpack-dev-server

But `webpack-server` is not a thing. Remove it.

If you look closely at your error message, it kinda tries to tell you the same thing:

> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>
> npm ERR! peer react@"~0.9" from webpack-server@0.1.2

It says that it fails to satisfy dependencies caused by this `webpack-server`. Make sure to get rid of it. That will at least fix this problem.

### Your next problem

NOTE however, that for further customization of `CRA`'s webpack build, given you don't want to `eject`, you also need a way to override it's default build settings.

For that, you might want to check out [`CRACO`](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

CRACO (like Webpack Module Federation) does not have very good documentation, but it has a few webpack-related examples [here](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/tree/master/recipes).